# I am new to the Salesforce platform.I have been getting "Attempt to de reference a null Object" on Custom Object Trigger.Help me to Sort the Error

Tags: apex, trigger, class

**Apex Trigger**

```
   trigger CustObjCToPTrigger on Employee__c (before update) {
        set<Id> ParentIdSet = new set<Id>();
        for(Employee__c e : trigger.new){
            
            if(trigger.oldMap.get(e.Id).Phone__c != 
               trigger.newMap.get(e.Id).Phone__c){
                ParentIdSet.add(e.Employer__c);
            }
            System.debug(ParentIdSet);
        }
        
        map<Id,Employer__c> parentMapObj = new map<Id,Employer__c>();
        list<Employer__c> elist = [select Id,Name,Phone__c from Employer__c where Id =: ParentIdSet];
        
        for(Employer__c eobj : elist){
            parentMapObj.put(eobj.Id, eobj);
        }
        
        System.debug(parentMapObj);
        
        for(Employee__c emobj : trigger.new){
            
            **parentMapObj.get(emobj.Id).Phone__c = emobj.Phone__c;**
**// Attempt to de reference null object on above line**
        }
        update parentMapObj.values();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple case of allowing for not having a parent ID in the map. In the first iteration you only get employers (parents) for employees with a phone number change, but in the last loop you assume you can find the employer (parent) for all employees.

Update the latter loop like:

```
for(Employee__c emobj : trigger.new){
    Employer__c employer = parentMapObj.get(emobj.Id);

    if (employer != null) {
        employer.Phone__c = emobj.Phone__c;
    }
}
```

PS: I personally would call the map `employerByEmployeeId` and call `emobj` just `employee`. This would make the code clearer.

Additionally, you should follow best practice and move this code into a "trigger handler" class rather than putting it directly in the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I really appreciate for the Help.Regards

Answer (score 0):

you should not put the values into map directly
first check if map has key or not (if true) then add the values to that key

You should add

```
ParentIdSet.add(e.Employer__c.Id);** in palce of ParentIdSet.add(e.Employer__c); 
for(Employer__c eobj : elist){
           if( parentMapObj.Containskey(eobj.Id)) {
           parentMapobj.get(eobj.Id).add(eobj);
        }
      else {
           parentMapObj.put(eobj.Id, eobj); 
           }
}
```

Try like this , I think the error will be solved

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your code. Please do not ask for "best answer" (there is no best answer here). See [answer] to learn more about writing answers on SFSE.

Comment: This answer is also incorrect. The asker is not using a "multimap" (with List-type values) and using one would not solve this problem. Changing `Employer__c` to `Employer__c.Id` is incorrect. The correct form would be `Employer__r.Id`, but `Employer__c` is the preferred way to get a relationship field's content.